# Why provide custom reference keys instead of childByAutoId in Firebase

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am just learning Firebase and I would like to know why one would need custom reference keys instead of just using `childByAutoId`. The examples from docs showed mostly similar to the following:

```
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "contacts": { "ghopper": true },
    },
    "ghopper": { ... },
    "eclarke": { ... }
  }
}
```

but why not use something like

```
{
  "users": {
    "gFlmT9skBHfxf7vCBCbhmxg6dll1": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "contacts": { "ghopper": true },
    },
    "gFlmT9skBHfxf7vCBCbhmxg6dll2": { ... },
    "gFlmT9skBHfxf7vCBCbhmxg6dll3": { ... }
  }
}
```

Though I would prefer the first example for readability purposes. Aside from that, would there be any impact regarding Firebase features and other development related things like querying, updating, etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase's `childByAutoId` method is great for generating the keys in a collection:

- Where the items need to be ordered by their insertion time
- Where the items don't have a natural key
- Where it is not a problem if the same item occurs multiple times

In a collection of users, none of these conditions (usually) apply: the order doesn't matter, users can only appear in the collection once, and the items **do** have a natural key.

That last one may not be clear from the sample in the documentation. Users stored in the Firebase Database usually come from a different system, often from Firebase Authentication. That system gives users a unique ID, in the case of Firebase Authentication called the **UID**. This UID is a unique identifier for the user. So if you have a collection of users, using their UID as the key makes it easy to find the users based on their ID. In the documentation samples, just read the keys as if they are (friendly readable versions of) the UID of that user.

In your example, imagine that you've read the node for Ada Lovelace and want to look up her contacts. You'd need the run a query on `/users`, which gets more and more expensive as you add users. But in the model from the documentation you know precisely what node you need to read: `/users/ghopper`.